# Kotlin: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class ViewModel

Tags: kotlin, architecture, components

This is my first project using Kotlin, so I'm practice to create an app and using architecture  components Room Database, Android View Model and LiveData, but I got this error message. 
And the mobile crash unexpectedly,

I don't know how to solve it.

Thanks.

The build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: "kotlin-kapt"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.leaf76.architectureexample"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
    def room_version = "2.2.5"


    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    // com.android.support.cardview => androidx
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    // com.android.support.design => androidx
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0"

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    // ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    // LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    // Annotation processor
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"

    // Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"

}
```

Error message

```
2020-03-27 02:50:27.987 12708-12708/com.leaf76.architectureexample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.leaf76.architectureexample, PID: 12708
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.leaf76.architectureexample/com.leaf76.architectureexample.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.leaf76.architectureexample.NoteViewModel
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3448)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3595)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7811)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.leaf76.architectureexample.NoteViewModel
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:221)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:187)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
    at com.leaf76.architectureexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:21)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7955)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7944)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3423)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3595) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7811) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076) 
 Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.leaf76.architectureexample.NoteViewModel> has no zero argument constructor
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:219)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:187) 
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150) 
    at com.leaf76.architectureexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:21) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7955) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7944) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3423) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3595) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2147) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7811) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076)
```

Note.kt

```
package com.leaf76.architectureexample

import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "note_table")
data class Note(var title: String, var description: String, var priorty: Int) {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var Id: Int = 0
}
```

NoteDatabase

```
package com.leaf76.architectureexample

import android.content.Context
import android.os.AsyncTask
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
import androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase

@Database(entities = [Note::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class NoteDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun noteDao(): NoteDao

    // static parameters
    companion object {

        private lateinit var instance: NoteDatabase

        fun getInstance(context: Context): NoteDatabase {
            if (instance == null) {
                synchronized(NoteDatabase::class.java) {
                    instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        NoteDatabase::class.java, "note_database"
                    )
                        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                        .addCallback(roomCallbackL)
                        .build()
                }
            }
            return instance
        }

        private val roomCallbackL: Callback = object : Callback() {
            override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                super.onCreate(db)
                PopulateDbAsyncTask(instance).execute()
            }
        }

        private class PopulateDbAsyncTask(db: NoteDatabase) : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            private val noteDao: NoteDao = db.noteDao()

            override fun doInBackground(vararg voids: Void): Void? {
                noteDao.insert(Note("Title1", "Description1", 1))
                noteDao.insert(Note("Title2", "Description2", 2))
                noteDao.insert(Note("Title3", "Description3", 3))
                return null
            }
        }

    }

}
```

NoteRepository
    package com.leaf76.architectureexample

```
import android.app.Application
import android.os.AsyncTask
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData

class NoteRepository(application: Application) {
    // The lateinit avoid Nullable
    private var noteDao: NoteDao

    private var allNotes: LiveData<List<Note>>

    init {
        val database = NoteDatabase.getInstance(application.applicationContext)
        noteDao = database.noteDao()
        allNotes = noteDao.getAllNotes()
    }

    fun insert(note: Note) {
        InsertNoteAsyncTask(noteDao).execute(note)
    }

    fun update(note: Note) {
        UpdateNoteAsyncTask(noteDao).execute(note)
    }

    fun delete(note: Note) {
        DeleteNoteAsyncTask(noteDao).execute(note)
    }

    fun deleteAllnotes() {
        DeleteAllNotesAsyncTask(noteDao).execute()
    }

    fun getAllNotes(): LiveData<List<Note>> {
        return allNotes
    }

    companion object {
        // Insert note
        private class InsertNoteAsyncTask(var noteDao: NoteDao) :
            AsyncTask<Note, Void, Void>() {

            override fun doInBackground(vararg notes: Note): Void? {
                noteDao.insert(notes[0])
                return null
            }
        }

        // Update note
        private class UpdateNoteAsyncTask(var noteDao: NoteDao) :
            AsyncTask<Note, Void, Void>() {

            override fun doInBackground(vararg notes: Note): Void? {
                noteDao.update(notes[0])
                return null
            }
        }

        // Delete note
        private class DeleteNoteAsyncTask(var noteDao: NoteDao) :
            AsyncTask<Note, Void, Void>() {

            override fun doInBackground(vararg notes: Note): Void? {
                noteDao.delete(notes[0])
                return null
            }
        }

        // Delete all note
        private class DeleteAllNotesAsyncTask(var noteDao: NoteDao) :
            AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            override fun doInBackground(vararg voids: Void): Void? {
                noteDao.deleteAllNotes()
                return null
            }
        }
    }

}
```

NoteViewModel

```
package com.leaf76.architectureexample

import android.app.Application
import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData

class NoteViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private var repository: NoteRepository = NoteRepository(application)
    private var allNotes: LiveData<List<Note>> = repository.getAllNotes()

    fun insert(note: Note){
        repository.insert(note)
    }

    fun update(note:Note){
        repository.update(note)
    }

    fun delete(note: Note){
        repository.delete(note)
    }

    fun deleteAllNotes(){
        repository.deleteAllnotes()
    }

    fun getAllNotes(): LiveData<List<Note>>{
        return allNotes
    }

}
```

MainActivity

```
package com.leaf76.architectureexample

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val TAG: String = "MainActivity"

    private lateinit var noteViewModel: NoteViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        Log.i(TAG,"MainActivity entry on create")

        noteViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(NoteViewModel::class.java)
        Log.i(TAG,"Get note view model")

        noteViewModel.getAllNotes().observe(this, Observer<List<Note>> {
            Toast.makeText(this,"onChanged",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        })
        Log.i(TAG, "Get Toast")
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to show all the code of these classes unrelated to the issue. We just need to see your code in MainActivity where you are getting your ViewModel reference.

Comment: Sorry, I added MainActivity code

Answer (score 0):

It works!!!

When I remove this instance==null condition, but I still don't know kotlin how to run it on Singleton pattern.

```
    // static parameters
    companion object {

        private lateinit var instance: NoteDatabase

        fun getInstance(context: Context): NoteDatabase {
            if (instance == null) {
                synchronized(NoteDatabase::class.java) {
                    instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        NoteDatabase::class.java, "note_database"
                    )
                        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                        .addCallback(roomCallbackL)
                        .build()
                }
            }
            return instance
        }
```

to

```
    // static parameters
    companion object {

        private lateinit var instance: NoteDatabase

        fun getInstance(context: Context): NoteDatabase {
                synchronized(NoteDatabase::class.java) {
                    instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        NoteDatabase::class.java, "note_database"
                    )
                        .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                        .addCallback(roomCallbackL)
                        .build()
            }
            return instance
        }
```

Comment: instance cannot be null (if it were of type NoteDatabase? then it could be null), rather as a lateinit it can be either uninitialized or initialized.